# How to Add Filter to Certain Years Or Between Certain Dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am writing a query that counts trips which exceed 20 minutes but is only in the years 2015, 2016, 2017. The code works fine, showing the years and number of trips per year, but the results show all years and not just these three. The issue is that the column start_time is a timestamp. I can do timestamp_add and then between (as shown below, disregard the number of days as they are just placeholders) but it just seems sloppy

I can do timestamp_add and then between (as shown below, disregard the number of days as they are just placeholders) but it just seems sloppy.

```
SELECT extract(year from start_time), count(*)
FROM `datapb.shopping.trips`
where duration_minutes > 20 and
      start_time between timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -1000 DAY) AND timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -350 DAY)
group by EXTRACT(YEAR from start_time)
```

Any suggestions would be fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use timestamp constants?

```
select extract(year from start_time) as yyyy, count(*)
from `datapb.shopping.trips`
where duration_minutes > 20 and
      start_time >= timestamp('2015-01-01') and
      start_time < timestamp('2018-01-01')
group by yyyy
order by yyyy;
```